# How to make marker line thicker in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, mac, markers

I'm mapping railways, find that the usual cross marker line is so thin it doesn't show up in Print Composer at web resolution, and can't find any way of making it thicker, only the main line. Is there a way in the just released 2.0? If not, how do I do it in 1.8?

My System is QGIS 1.8.0 on OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust 'Outline width' parameter:

[image]

Comment: I assume this is 2.0? The window is nothing like 1.8 anyway...

Comment: @johnsankey, yes it is 2.0. You asked for 2.0 didn't you? There is no such option in 1.8.

Comment: The option is there in 1.8. Just in a different place.